# C# Regular Expression Help - grouping with optional data points

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Given 2 different lines I'm parsing, I need to extract the data points into regex match groups.

Example Line 1:

Header values are as follows:

```
DATE{space}TYPE{space}DESCR{space}VOLUME{space}RATE{space}TOTAL
[11/30/15] [CF] [DISC 1] [28270.18] [0.00150] [-42.41]
```

Example Line 2:

```
DATE{space}TYPE{space}DESCR{space}VOLUME{space}RATE{space}TOTAL
[11/30/15] [CF] [OTHER VOLUME FEES] [28186.68] [0.00008] [-2.25]
```

I'm using the following regex to get matches:

```
(?<date>^\d{1,2}[-/.]\d{1,2}[-/.]\d{1,2}[\d+])\s+(?<type>[A-Za-z]{2})\s+(?<descr>\w+\s+.*?(1))\s+.*?(?<volume>(\d+(?:\.\d+?))\s+.*?(?<rate>([0]?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)))\s+(?<total>[-+]?\d+[.,]\d+)?.*$")
```

I can match the first case,but never the second case. there will always be a total, but they may NOT always be volume or rate. In addition, volume can be whole, decimal or code (e.g. "1B").

What am I missing here?

The description field is an open field and may contain "1" in it. I can have several words in it, or just 1.

Comment: Regex seems really, really bad for this job.  Why not just split on whitespace and access by index?

Comment: Agreed.  Even *if* you get that regex to work, in a month you won't have any idea how the regex works, and even minor changes will take a while.  You're better of writing something clearer to understand.

Comment: Can you describe in simple terms how you want your lines to be broken up?  I imagine there is a much simpler and easier way to solve this.  I do not want to even attempt to decipher that regex mess so just explain what each "part" is and we can come up with alternative solutions

Comment: I've considered other options. I cannot split on whitespaces bc the description field will vary. I need to extract the date first, then type, then description field (open field), then the volume, rate and total. volume and rate are also optional.

Comment: @GeorgeRios I still think you can do a whitespace split, just need some extra logic in there.  The first "part" is always a date right?  Then the next "part" is a description field that could include its own whitespace?  Are numbers allowed in the description field?

Comment: Yes, description can contain numbers as well.

Comment: If you want to go with regex, I highly recommend you use the `IgnoreWhitespace` flag and split your regex onto multiple lines with comments.  This way maintaining it will be *far* easier.  It does look like splitting by spaces would be better though.  Split, first segment is a date, last three segments are numerical values, the rest is the description.

Comment: I'm not married to using REGEX for this. But it seemed like a powerful tool that I've used in the past in these use cases. Parsing splits on white spaces feels very brittle to me.

Comment: I'm assuming from your attempted regex that the square braces are not actually in the source data? [Otherwise this would be trivial without regex]

Comment: Yes I used [] to show the individual fields that needed to be captured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your log lines contain 6 fields, but the 4th and 5th can go missing. A common way to match optional fields is using an *optional non-capturing group*, `(?:...)?`. These groups do not make a separate memory buffers for the text they match, that is why they are useful to keep matching cleaner and more efficient.

*NOTE* that in .NET, there is a way to make all non-named capturing groups non-capturing by use of [`RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_ExplicitCapture) option.

Your fixed regex mau look like

```
^(?<date>\d{1,2}[-/.]\d{1,2}[-/.]\d{1,2})\s+(?:(?<type>[A-Z]{2})\s+)?(?:(?<descr>\w.*?)\s+)?(?:(?<volume>\d*\.?\d+)\s+)?(?:(?<rate>\d*\.?\d+)\s+)?(?<total>[-+]?\d*[.,]?\d+)\s*$
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3Cdate%3E%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D%5B-%2F.%5D%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D%5B-%2F.%5D%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D%29%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3Ctype%3E%5BA-Z%5D%7B2%7D%29%5Cs%2B%29%3F%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3Cdescr%3E%5Cw.*%3F%29%5Cs%2B%29%3F%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3Cvolume%3E%5Cd*%5C.%3F%5Cd%2B%29%5Cs%2B%29%3F%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3Crate%3E%5Cd*%5C.%3F%5Cd%2B%29%5Cs%2B%29%3F%28%3F%3Ctotal%3E%5B-%2B%5D%3F%5Cd*%5B.%2C%5D%3F%5Cd%2B%29%5Cs*%24&i=11%2F30%2F15%20CF%20DISC%201%2028270.18%200.00150%20-42.41%20%20%0D%0A11%2F30%2F15%20CF%20OTHER%20VOLUME%20FEES%2028186.68%200.00008%20-2.25%20%0D%0A11%2F30%2F15%20CF%20DUES%20%26%20ASSESSMENTS%20-3.57%0D%0A11%2F30%2F15%20CF%20INTERCHANGE%20-68.34%20&o=m).

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (when `RegexOptions.Multiline` is used)
- `(?<date>\d{1,2}[-/.]\d{1,2}[-/.]\d{1,2})` - Group "date": 1-2 digits and then 2 repetitions of `-`/`/`/`.` followed with 1-2 digits (thus, this pattern can be written as `(?<date>\d{1,2}(?:[-/.]\d{1,2}){2})`).
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `(?:(?<type>[A-Z]{2})\s+)?` - an optional group matching 2 uppercase ASCII letters, captured into Group "type", and then 1+ whitespaces
- `(?:(?<descr>\w.*?)\s+)?` - an optional group matching a word char (letter, digit or `_` and some other special chars (like diacritics) followed with any 0+ chars other than a newline char LF, as few as possible, all this captured into Group "descr", and then 1+ whitespaces
- `(?:(?<volume>\d*\.?\d+)\s+)?` - an optional group matching  0+ digits, an optional `.` and then 1+ digits (that is, floats or integers) captured into Group "volume", then 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?:(?<rate>\d*\.?\d+)\s+)?` - an optional group matching  a float or integer values captured into Group "rate", and then 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?<total>[-+]?\d*[.,]?\d+)` - Group "total": an optional `-` or `+` followed with 0+ digits, an optional `.` or `,` and then 1+ digits (so, positive or negative floats or integers are matched)
- `\s*` - any 0+ trailing whitespaces
- `$` - end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

`(?<date>^\d{1,2}[-/.]\d{1,2}[-/.]\d{1,2}[\d+])\s+(?<type>[A-Z]{2})\s+(?<descr>\w+.*?\s+)(?<volume>\d+[.]?\d+)\s+(?<rate>\d+[.]?\d+)\s+(?<total>[-+]?\d+[.,]\d+?.*$)`

Yes. This is a fairly complex regex. But if you have varying spaces inside your grouping, you can use .*?\s+ to end on the last space. This seems to work nicely for all the use cases I have.

Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Add some more tests on your "volume" field. Looks to me like volumes of single digits, or the "1B" code you mentioned in your post, won't be parsed.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. You're right that case didn't work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - thank you! I just updated it to make some values optional as well. https://regex101.com/r/Y6YSVh/2

Comment: I posted the answer below

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Excellent response and analysis. your regex is solid!